# How to use Powershell to rename file extension containing a space char

Tags: powershell

I have a bunch of images that are named `IMG_0182.JPG (2)` with the extension being `.JPG (2)`.

How can I use Powershell to  batch rename these extensions to `.jpg`?

When I use `Get-ChildItem *.* | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '.JPG (2)','.jpg' }` per the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-7) I get no changes, presumably because the extension has a space in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to escape the parenthesis and the space (and the dot as noted by Theo)

```
Get-ChildItem *.* | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '\.JPG\ \(2\)$','.jpg' }
```

Comment: Yes, but you are forgetting the dot `.` also has special meaning in regex (_any character_), so you need to escape that too. Also, I would use the 'End-Of-String' anchor `$` like `-replace '\.JPG\s*\(\d+\)$', '.jpg'`

Answer (score 2):

A variant on the above. You have to escape certain characters when using `-replace` as it expects a regular expression. I would use the in-built .Net method instead.

```bsh
Get-ChildItem *.* | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.FullName.Replace('.jpg (2)',".jpg") }
```